# In a saga with Nestjs, I get an error from rxjs of type hostReportError

Tags: node.js, rxjs, cqrs, nestjs, saga

I am currently setting up an article publication system (cut in a CQRS fashion) with a saga that listens if an article is ready to be published. The saga is as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class ArticleSaga {
    @Saga()
    articleRegister = (events$: Observable<any>): Observable<ICommand> => {
        return events$
          .pipe(
              ofType(RegisterArticleEvent),
              delay(1000),
              map((event: {
                  uuid: string,
                  statut: string,
                  createBodyArticleDto: CreateBodyArticleDto,
              }) => {

                  return new PublishArticleCommand(event.uuid, event.statut, event.createBodyArticleDto);
              }),
          );
    }
}
```

But when I create an article, the command performing this operation works well, but the saga that listens to this command to launch the publication command throws an error that I do not understand and that I do not know how to solve. The error is as follows:

```
.../node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/hostReportError.js:4
    setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);

CommandHandlerNotFoundException {
  message: 'CommandHandler not found exception!'
}
```

Handler PublishArticleHandler :

```
@CommandHandler(PublishArticleCommand)
export class PublishArticleHandler implements ICommandHandler<PublishArticleCommand> {
    constructor(
        private readonly publicRepository: PublicRepository,
    ) {}

    async execute(command: PublishArticleCommand) {...}
```

and PublishArticleCommand:

```
export class PublishArticleCommand implements ICommand {
    constructor(
        public readonly uuid: string,
        public readonly statut: string,
        public readonly createBodyArticleDto: CreateBodyArticleDto,
    ) {}
}
```

If anyone understands this problem and has the solution, I would be very happy to read it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found why I had this error, the `PublishArticleHandler` handler was not imported into the module.